# How can I export the contents of a data bound datagridview to word in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-word, export

I have found ways to do this in c# or asp.net, but I need VB.net. I have a dataviewgrid that I need  to export to a .doc file (i am sure I can figure out the formatting and such of the doc). Or, if that is too complex, to an excel file.

There seems to be many asp.net examples, but nothing that works in vb studio on vb.

Comment: Do you mean VB.Net as in a desktop application?

Comment: yes. I have a windows form application I made that has a couple databound datagridviews that I would like to export to a doc file (guess it would be some tables). Failing that, I would like to be able to print them right from the windows application. Exporting would be better though. Ideally, I would copy a word template, then write the datagridview contents to it (it is just text, no images)

Comment: [Export DataGridView to Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/472706/Export-DataGridView-to-Excel).

Comment: Thanks again, looks like it may solve the excel export. Got all the code in, but in the class i made for it, it does not recognize xlworksheet. says it is undeclared. Any idea? Did the code exactly like the example.

Comment: Here is another one that may work better for you:http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?626953-export-DGV-to-word-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past displayed the datagridview on screen and changed the mime type of the page to application/excel.  It will automatically open in an embedded excel file.

Try this link for how to do it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317719

Comment: -*Thanks, though seems this is for a web? sorry, I am really new to this, and self teaching vb in vb studio for a windows application.